# Swift: Refreshing UIImageView Image

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Half of my window is a `UITableView` and other is a `PageViewController`.

In my PageViewController, I have two properties:

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayImageView: UIImageView!
var displayImage : UIImage?
```

PageViewController `viewDidLoad` I assign:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.displayImageView.image = self.displayImage
   }
```

`displayImageView` is an `outlet` connected to my scene in `Storyboard`.  As the `User` taps different cells, I would like the image in `displayImageView` to change.

In my `parentViewController` that displays the `tableView` and the `PageViewController`, I call the following method in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func getDisplayImageForSelectedRow() {
    var row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
    //DisplayImageVC is a contentViewController that is loaded by pageViewController
    var displayImageVC = self._pageContent[1] as DisplayImageVC
    displayImageVC.displayImage = self._displayImage[row!] as UIImage
    println(displayImageVC.displayImage)
    if (self.isPageViewVisible){
        displayImageVC.displayImageView.reloadInputViews()
        displayImageVC.displayImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Here the log from `println()`:

```
You selected cell #0
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7c21c2e0>)
You selected cell #1
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7c21c5a0>)
You selected cell #2
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7c21cd00>)
You selected cell #3
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7c21cff0>)
You selected cell #4
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7c21d2d0>)
```

Based on the log, I presume a new image is being assigned; however, the `UIImageView` outlet continues to show the same image that was loaded the first time pageViewController was loaded.

As you may have noticed in the code, I have tried the following lines to code to get the UIImageView to refresh, but no avail:

```
displayImageVC.displayImageView.reloadInputViews()
displayImageVC.displayImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

How can I get the `UIImageView` to show the new image that was loaded?

Comment: displayImage.image = ...
Minor mix up I think.

Comment: displayImage is a UIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getDisplayImageForSelectedRow` you are only updating the UIImage, you should also assign the image to the view.:

```
func getDisplayImageForSelectedRow() {
   ..
  displayImageVC.displayImage = self._displayImage[row!] as UIImage
  displayImageVC.displayImageView.image = displayImageVC.displayImage <--THIS
  ..
}
```

Comment: Actually that caused a crashed b/c I don't think you should set the IBOutlet  property from another class.  However, I created a method in the child and called:  `   func refershUIImageView() {
        self.planImageView.image = self.planImage
    }
`

Comment: Glad it helped, but the crash must have had a different cause (I.e., not the fact that we were setting an outlet from another class. An outlet is just a property that is initialized in a given way, nothing more, nothing less)